How can I statically find all passed arguments to a function in a codebase?
In an attempt to find unused translations in an application, I'd like to find all passed arguments to a function that can be statically determined. What's the best way to go about this problem? Introspection? Using code mods or similar that can parse the AST?
Scenarios that I'd like to cover are e.g.:

translate("abc"); // "abc"
const arg = "abc"; translate(arg); // "abc"
const arg1 = "abc"; const arg2 = "xyz"; translate(arg1 + arg2); // "abcxyz"
const arg1 = "abc"; const arg2 = "xyz"; const arg = arg1 + arg2; translate(arg); // "abcxyz"
const arg = "abc"; const getArg = () => arg; translate(getArg()); // "abc"

If there are also non-static invocations on the form translate(getUserInput()), then I'd be happy if I could get that as well as "getUserInput()" or similar. But this scenario is not crucial.
I would like to get an array of all arguments, not having to "review search results" in the editor or terminal.
Any tips out there?

So, you're trying to get an array containing all values that went through translate() so that you can erase from the translation file the entries that were not translated? Can your test guarantee that all possible routes that leads to a translate() will be triggered? Because if not, your approach is not good enough, because you can mistakenly erase some text of a route that is not reached often.

It's not the end of the world. We have full code coverage in our tests and rely on it.

How about decorating the translate function via e.g. an around or after method-modifier? In order to achieve your goal you could slightly change the code of one of the proposed solutions to following question "How does one access the arguments of a function call when this function can not be rewritten due to its unknown implementation?".
